# How to add an existing stored procedure to dbcontext with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have an existing stored procedure that takes in several parameters. I'm trying to call it using EF Core.

Here is what I've got:

```
var results = _context.{this is where I need help}.FromSqlRaw( "mystoredproc  @param1 = {0}, @param2 = {1}, @param3 = {2}, @param4 = {3}", request.Date1, request.Date2, request.Date3, request.Date4).ToList();
```

My model looks like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    // more properties but left out for space concerns
}
```

In my `DbContext` I've added:

```
public DbSet<MyModel> MyModel { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // not sure what to do here
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to do in the `OnModelCreating`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `Database` property, as in:

```
var results = _context.Database.FromSqlRaw( "mystoredproc  @param1 = {0}, @param2 = {1}, @param3 = {2}, @param4 = {3}", request.Date1, request.Date2, request.Date3, request.Date4).ToList();
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.database?view=efcore-3.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-3.1.

Comment: That gives an error of "DatabaseFacade" does not contain a definition for "FromSqlRaw" and no accessible extension method 'FromSqlRaw' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found...

Comment: You need to add a using statement for Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.Infrastructure.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastrucure, sorry for the wrong casing!

Answer (score 0):

You call stored procedure this way as well

```
 var myIdParam = new SqlParameter("@MyId", myid);
 var monthParam = new SqlParameter("@Month", month);
 var labelParam = new SqlParameter("@Label", label);
 return await _context.MyModel.FromSqlRaw("EXEC mystoredproc @MyId,@Month,@Label ", new[] { myIdParam, monthParam,labelParam}).ToListAsync();
```